# Use wireguard to establish a tunnel between two NATted clients and a middleman and then route all traffic from one client to another

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, nat, wireguard

I have three Linux/Debian hosts: Client, Middleman, and Gateway.
The Client and the Gateway are behind NAT, while Middleman has a public IPv4 address.

Thus, the `Endpoint` for Client and Gateway will be the middleman.
Then, I want to route all the traffic from the Client in this way:

`Client ==> Middleman ==> Gateway ==> Internet`

My current configs are:

## Client

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51821

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
Endpoint = MIDDLEMAN_PUBLIC_IP:51823
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

## Middleman

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.3/32
ListenPort = 51823

PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1


# Client
[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32

# Gateway
[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24
```

## Gateway

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
ListenPort = 51822

# From wg0 to eth0
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE


[Peer]
PublicKey = 
Endpoint = MIDDLEMAN_PUBLIC_IP:51823
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

At the moment the tunnel is working and I can ssh from Client to Gateway thought Wireguard's tunnel, but the Internet traffic is stuck at the middleman (according to TCP dump, trying to ping 8.8.8.8).

I'm definitively missing some iptables rules on the Middleman, but I've tried several ones from different online guides.

Can you suggest me the working configurations?

Comment: On `Middleman`, the `[Peer]` for `Gateway` needs to have `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` instead, but the side effect is that `Middleman` itself will use `Gateway` as its Internet gateway as well, unless you have `Table=off` under `[Interface]` and set up policy routing manually.